# TimeSpan DataFormatString in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with an ObjectDataSource that comes from a linq query.

One of the variables of the source is a timespan and I'm binding a boundfield with the DataField="MyTimeSpanVariable". The data  contains times in seconds and minutes and very rarely in hours.

The data displays fine in its native format but when I add HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm:ss}" to the boundfield properties in the aspx page, it crashes on the MyGridView.Databind() line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you like, you can try formatting your field on the Grid's RowDataBound event.

For example:

```
Protected Sub YourGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles YourGridView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.DataItem("YourColName") Then
            'Do formatting
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx
Eq to use in Asp.Net MVC Metadata:

```
DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}")
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem!:
`FormatException on DataFormatString="Mødetidspunkt er {0:H:mm}"`

You can't use two colons, so use the short time format specifier.

```
DataFormatString="Time is {0:t}"
```

```
t is the equivalent of HH:mm
T is the equivalent of HH:mm:ss
```

See ["Standard DateTime Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to escape the second ':' if you are using C#. For example:

```
DataFormatString=@"Time is {0:H\:mm}";
```

Answer (score 3):

From the aspx/ascx this would be something like

```
HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:mm\:ss}"
```