# DataFormatString for time (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net

I tried to re-format the time displayed in GridView by only showing `HH:mm`. Currenly my time displayed is `HH:mm:ss`. Coding as follow.

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="thStyle" DataField="time" HeaderText="Time Upload" />
```

I tried `DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}"` but when I run the system it threw me an error which is

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the answers in [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703695/timespan-dataformatstring-in-gridview).

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons thank you for the useful information. I tried those solution given `DataFormatString="{0:t}"` and it sill returning me `HH:mm:ss` . If I use `YourGridView_RowDataBound` it will give me error **Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Boolean' is not valid** on the line `If e.Row.DataItem("YourColName") Then`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manage to get the `HH:mm` using `HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:hh\:mm}"`

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Emerald got me there even though I don't think it's quite right - it at least has a couple of typos. This worked for me:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

I didn't need the `HtmlEncode=false`, but if you find yourself wanting to try it note that that `false` should not be in quotation marks. The `ApplyFormatInEditMode` isn't necessary for the formatting to work but in my experience you want it set to true more often than not.